# How Ethereum addresses get added to the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, addresses

I feel like this is a very basic question but here it go: I'm familiar with the process of generating an Ethereum address (from a seed prhase to private key, to public key to ethereum address). What I'm wondering is **how can I get this address added and public to the blockchain?** I've read in a few places that I'd need to start a transaction and the transaction should be broadcasted to a node, which makes sense. But if the ethereum address is brand new and not in the blockchain yet, how would I add funds to it in order to create a transaction? How would I be able to pay gas fees and such? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright,  I understand your concern.  However the answer is simple.  Your address is "already" there.

Any properly generated address is valid for blockchain usage. **However** it's not written into blockchain until there was some transactions related to it.

For example,  if you were to generate a new address and send funds to it, your new address is now "written " into the blockchain,  as there was a transaction including it.

So to conclude: You don't have to **add** address to blockchain in other to be able to use it. You just need to have a private key for it so you can control any funds sent to that address.

Comment: Oh okay, got it! I guess I was thinking from a database perspective where we have to add entries to it. Thank you for the answer, that clarified a lot of things for me!